# How do I speed up file I/O in PyPy3?

Tags: io, cpython, pypy

In CPython, I'm able to read a 1.6 GB file in 11 seconds, using `lines = f.read().splitlines()`, while in  PyPy3, the exact same code takes 2 minutes to read the file. Using `f.read().split('\n')` manages to do it in 1 minute, but is still much slower than CPython. The reason I want to use PyPy is that the loop I do later over `lines` is way faster in PyPy, but I'm still curious why PyPy is slower than CPython for file I/O, and how I might possibly speed it up.

Comment: I'm investigating why pypy3 seems much slower than pypy2 and cpython there.  I guess it's not exactly what you're looking for but the next pypy3 release we'll do will see better results.

Comment: If you can, you may find that streaming the file works better than reading it all in one go:

with open('path/to/file') as f:


    for line in f:

        processline(line)

Comment: @mattip thanks for your reply. yes, i have noticed that, and that's what i ended up using. but it's still a curiosity that f.read() is so slow in pypy...

Comment: @ArminRigo thanks for your reply. looking forward to the next pypy3 release. please do let us know the reason for the difference in speed, if you figure it out :)

Comment: The main issue was internal: it turns out that pypy3 does 5 copies of the result of `read()` before returning it, whereas pypy2 manages with only 1.  For large strings this is extremely costly.  This was fixed in the changeset number 119c84856339, in case you want to dig.

Comment: Thank you @ArminRigo, for figuring out what the issue was. Where can I access the update?

Comment: https://buildbot.pypy.org/nightly/py3.6/.  It probably helps a lot, but it may still be slower than CPython.  Please report the updated measures you do!

Comment: Awesome. Once i've updated and run again, I'll revert back with results. Thanks @ArminRigo

Comment: @ArminRigo I tested the latest build for MacOS (from 2020-07-03) on the same 1.6GB file, and the performance unfortunately is the same as before.

Comment: Unsure how you expect a version older than your question to contain the fix I did in reply to your version.  But indeed, I see there haven't been more recent builds on OS X.  I'll ask around.

Comment: Oops, totally missed that. I was confusing July with June for some odd reason :) Thank you again for investigating. I’ll check in regularly for a new macOS build

Comment: I am having the same issues.  Were you able to speed up reading/iterating a file using pypy?